# How do I change my code from callback function to promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have  a code like this below. The code still use callback function and i want to change using promise. I hesistate how to change them. can you help how change it

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir('/', (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message)
  }
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir('/')` is already promise, you need to resolve it either with `chaining` like you did or with syntax sugare using `async/await` inside [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
(async () => {
   try{
        const result = await fs.readdir('/');
        console.log(result)
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err.message)
   }
})();
```

Comment: This only works if you require the correct version of `fs`. -> `const fs = require('fs').promises`

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you import asycronous version of `readdir()` which is located in `require('fs').promises` you can read directories asyncronouly

```
const fs = require('fs').promises

const asyncReadDir = async(dirName) => {
    try {
         const dirData = await fs.readdir(dirName)
         console.log("Read successfully")
         // other code here
    } catch(error){
         // catch errors
         console.log(error)
    }
}

asyncReadDir("/downloads")
```